# undefiend font and size in HtmlEditorExtender?

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am using HtmlEditorExtender in aspx page.

In editor Font and (font) Size drop down shows fonts and font sizes but other then these fonts and sizes it also shows many items with text Undefiend.

Any guidance please.